# sklearn Pipeline for custome operations

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have been trying to create a pipeline for some basic classification task. Though, I am unable to find how to implement the below operations using sklearn.Pipeline

1. Add some steps just for training data & not test data
2. Implement a 'df.apply' sort of function

I tried reading some medium blogs & documentation but in vain.

Comment: Need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are probably lots of ways to do this. It's not strictly speaking something you necessarily have to do with `sklearn.Pipeline`. You might use something like `airflow` to orchestrate the steps of your classification task, or you could even use something like `zenml` which is built to exactly handle these kinds of tasks. You can wrap each of your steps in a simple `@step` decorator, then chain them together in a pipeline.

The [quickstart guide](https://docs.zenml.io/quickstart-guide) has a simple example that I think might well suit your purposes. Otherwise check out the [Github page](https://github.com/maiot-io/zenml/) for more details.

Disclaimer: I'm an engineer working at ZenML myself, so this is admittedly biased! Nevertheless, I think it might be useful for you. You can even do things like run your pipelines on an Airflow orchestrator pretty easily.